# ssrs 2008 R2 Main Report Deployment without Subreports

Tags: reporting-services

I prepared a report. I have used 15 subreports for the main report. When I deploy my report then all the subreports are also deployed in the Report Manager. I just want to see Main Report in the Report Manager instead of all reports. The snapshots are below. Is there any way advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to go to the properties of the sub reports and hide them in tile view. You can't actually completely hide them but this will hide them from most users.